# In Pytorch Geometric, for a neighborloader, how does is_sorted work?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I am confused how is_sorted works in pytorch geometric's [neighborloader](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/loader.html#torch_geometric.loader.NeighborLoader).  According to the docs, if you the data's `edge_index` is sorted by column, you can use `is_sorted=true` to save time and memory.  However, when I try it, I receive substantially different batch sizes.

Here's an example:

```
import torch
import torch_geometric as pyg
from torch_geometric.datasets import KarateClub

data_kc = KarateClub()
print(data_kc.data)
print(data_kc.data.edge_index)

loader_f = pyg.loader.NeighborLoader(data_kc.data, num_neighbors=[2,2,2], batch_size=3, is_sorted=False, shuffle=False)
loader_t = pyg.loader.NeighborLoader(data_kc.data, num_neighbors=[2,2,2], batch_size=3, is_sorted=True, shuffle=False)

b_f = next(iter(loader_f))
b_t = next(iter(loader_t))

print("batch with is_sorted=False =", b_f)
print("batch with is_sorted=True  =",b_t)
```

Output:

```
Data(x=[34, 34], edge_index=[2, 156], y=[34], train_mask=[34])
tensor([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,
          1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,
          3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,
          7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13,
         13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21,
         21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27,
         27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31,
         31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33,
         33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 21, 31,  0,  2,
          3,  7, 13, 17, 19, 21, 30,  0,  1,  3,  7,  8,  9, 13, 27, 28, 32,  0,
          1,  2,  7, 12, 13,  0,  6, 10,  0,  6, 10, 16,  0,  4,  5, 16,  0,  1,
          2,  3,  0,  2, 30, 32, 33,  2, 33,  0,  4,  5,  0,  0,  3,  0,  1,  2,
          3, 33, 32, 33, 32, 33,  5,  6,  0,  1, 32, 33,  0,  1, 33, 32, 33,  0,
          1, 32, 33, 25, 27, 29, 32, 33, 25, 27, 31, 23, 24, 31, 29, 33,  2, 23,
         24, 33,  2, 31, 33, 23, 26, 32, 33,  1,  8, 32, 33,  0, 24, 25, 28, 32,
         33,  2,  8, 14, 15, 18, 20, 22, 23, 29, 30, 31, 33,  8,  9, 13, 14, 15,
         18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]])
batch with is_sorted=False = Data(x=[17, 34], edge_index=[2, 25], y=[17], train_mask=[17], input_id=[3], batch_size=3)
batch with is_sorted=True  = Data(x=[3, 34], edge_index=[2, 2], y=[3], train_mask=[3], input_id=[3], batch_size=3)
```

I think this `edge_index` is sorted by column unless I'm really mis-understanding what they mean by sorted by column.  We then can see that the batch size is 17 vs 3 for `is_sorted=False` vs `is_sorted=True`.

I am running with pytorch version 1.12.1 and pytorch geometric version 2.2.0.